# Refresh tag info

Tags: reactjs, axios

have some problem, do little pokedex, have  after chose the cound of cards on the page i need to reload a container with cards, can u help me?

To get selected item use onSelect,

```
handleSelect  = (e) => {
    this.setState({value:e})
  }
<DropdownButton
            variant="danger"
            alignRight
            id="dropdown-menu-align-right"
            onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
```

and get it to link in component Pokemon list

```
<div className="col">
          <PokemonList pages={this.value} />
        </div>
```

PokemonList working like this

```
function PokemonList({ pages }) {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=${pages}`
  );
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState();
  const [prevPage, setPrevPage] = useState();
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel;
    axios
      .get(currPage, {
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPokemonList(res.data.results);
        setPrevPage(res.data.previous);
        setNextPage(res.data.next);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return () => {
      cancel();
    };
  }, [currPage, pageNum]);
```

i don't know but after select item at deop down, nothing changes, can u please help me

Comment: Are you sure that onSelect property even exist on DropdownButton ?

Comment: @TomaszKisiel i tried to do it with console.log(), so in state i had right value, remake it like this
`const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setValue(e);
  }`

Answer (score 2):

Find the problem, i tried to change only value, but i should to change the link, so answer was:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCurrPage(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${pageNum}&limit=${e}`);
  };
```

Comment: Hi. I was about to write an answer to your old question - "How to pass data from one component to the other". Let me know if you haven't yet solved that. The question was confusing but a valid one :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to store props inside state and with useEffect listen on state change. Because of this React can't properly update components. The currPage state doesn't change when pages change. You should avoid this because it's [anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state).

Working short example:

```
const Component = ({pages}) => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);

  useEffect( () => {
    fetch("/api/pokemons/" + pages )
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( data => setPokemonList(data.pokemonList ))
      .catch( err => console.log("handle errors") )
  })

  return <div>{ pokemonList.map( pokemon => <div>{ pokemon.name }</div>) }</div>
}
```

Comment: i'm new in react, styding like 2 weaks, so can u explain how i should to change my code and press your snippet